# Comparing data between two tables without except operator when having null values in fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server which will give me the difference between two tables

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.emp
except
SELECT * FROM #temp1
```

and I get the proper result with only one record (which is correct)

But when I use a left outer join

```
SELECT emp.* FROM emp
LEFT JOIN #temp1 ON emp.empid = #temp1.empid 
and
emp.firstname = #temp1.firstname 
AND emp.lastname = #temp1.lastname 
and emp.salary = #temp1.salary
and emp.dob = #temp1.dob
WHERE #temp1.empid IS NULL;
```

I get 39 records. Why the difference? I have mentioned all the columns in my join condition.

I know how to do this via where clause but my intention is to learn why the outer join is not working. Basically what is it that I am doing wrong

The below code works

```
SELECT dbo.emp.* FROM dbo.emp
JOIN #temp1 ON emp.empid = #temp1.empid 
where
emp.firstname <> #temp1.firstname 
or emp.lastname <> #temp1.lastname 
or emp.salary <> #temp1.salary
or emp.dob <> #temp1.dob;
```

Comment: Maybe because it's an outer join? Although if you're using SQL Server there is no difference between `LEFT` and `LEFT OUTER`...

Comment: yep, you are right and I added more info about what I am trying to do. Edited the OP.

Comment: Well, if the purpose is to learn why `LEFT OUTER` join works this way, are you sure the `EXCEPT` clause should return the same records as doing a `LEFT OUTER`? EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query.

Comment: Well I was trying to use left join to replicate the "except" functionality. What I assume was a left join would return all records which are common to the right and null if it doesnt exits. So when I select a record whose id= null, I should get the record which is different than the one on the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer join is presumably not working because some of the fields have `NULL` values.

You can emulate the `except` using `union all` and `group by`:

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM ((select 'emp' as which, empid, firstname, lastname, salary, dob
       from emp
      ) union all
      (select 'temp', empid, firstname, lastname, salary, dob
       from @temp1
      )
     ) t
group by empid, firstname, lastname, salary, dob
having sum(case when which = 'temp' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

EDIT:

You can do this with a `join` using more complex conditions:

```
SELECT emp.*
FROM emp LEFT JOIN
     #temp1
     ON (emp.empid = #temp1.empid or coalesce(emp.empid, #temp1.empid) is null) and
        (emp.firstname = #temp1.firstname or coalesce(emp.firstname, #temp1.firstname) is null) and
        (emp.lastname = #temp1.lastname or coalesce(emp.lastname, #temp1.lastname) is null)  and
        (emp.salary = #temp1.salary or coalesce(emp.salary,  #temp1.salary) is null) and
        (emp.dob = #temp1.dob or  or coalesce(emp.dob, #temp1.dob ) is null)
WHERE #temp1.empid IS NULL;
```

Comment: I tried this

`SELECT t.*
FROM ((select 'emp' as which, empid, firstname, lastname, salary, dob
       from emp
      ) union all
      (select 'temp', empid, firstname, lastname, salary, dob
       from #temp1
      )
     ) t
group by empid, firstname, lastname, salary, dob, t.which
having sum(case when which = 'temp' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;`

But I get back all the rows. I checked by removing the having clause and I see the record which is different at the top though bit its not getting selected when using the having clause.

Comment: @Navyseal . . . Could there be other subtle differences, such as the types not being the same for all the columns?

Comment: nope...all data types are same in the both the tables.

Comment: your second solution works as you rightly said earlier, some of the fields are nulls. The coalesce did the trick. But I liked the first approach too. Thanks mate.